# web api - I get 10 for a decimal property, but I want 10.00

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi service that returns an object with value field that is a decimal.  The problem is when the value is 10.00, I receive the following json:

```
{
     "value" : 10
}
```

but i want

```
{
     "value" : 10.00
}


public class SomethingDto
{
    public decimal value { get; set; }
}
```

I am playing around with JsonConverters but cant quite get my finger on what I need to do to have my service output 10.00 instead of 10 for my decimal property.  Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You can use [DataType("decimal(16 ,3")] over value

Comment: Why does it matter?  Any JSON parser is going to parse `10` and `10.00` to the same value.

Comment: [DataType("decimal(16 ,3")]  doesnt do it either

Comment: Even if you forced it to emit `10.00` it wouldn't help your API users unless they're using some weird, custom parser. `JSON.parse()`, for instance, will turn that into a flat `10`, e.g.: `JSON.parse('{"value":10.00}').value // 10`. These numbers don't carry with them any inherent formatting info. If you want to format a number you'll have to use a string. That, or return a more complicated object which describes to the client how the numeric value should be formatted for display.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the value to be formatted in the JSON and still remain a number when parsed, you can do this with a custom `JsonConverter`.  However, be forewarned that when clients parse the JSON with a standard parser, the formatting will be lost.  This is because formatting is not stored with numeric values.  The only way to preserve the formatting is to output the numbers as strings, as was already mentioned by several others.

Here is the code you would need for the converter:

```
public class DecimalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(decimal));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(((decimal)value).ToString("0.00"));
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jKzK4B

To use this converter with Web API, you need to insert it into the configuration.  Add this to the `Register` method in the `WebApiConfig` class:

```
var jsonSettings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
jsonSettings.C‌​onverters.Add(new DecimalConverter());
```

Note: if you do decide that you want to output your decimals as preformatted strings instead of as numbers, then you can use the same converter with one small change. In the `WriteJson` method, change `WriteRawValue` to `WriteValue`.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JxjmRZ

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a string return type for this and in your get property use a string.format to return the value to the required decimal places.Or you can try this in your jsonconverter

Comment: wouldnt that give me the following json? { "value" : "10.00" }

Comment: Yes. But if you are only looking for a textual format representation, then string is what you need. If you want to use decimal only which needs to be further processed, you dont need the formatting in the first place. Can you point out reason why u needed it to be rounded to 2 decimal places?

Comment: there is no good reason.  its a display thing for the front-end, im trying to avoid front-end dev for all consumers of the api.  if its not possible then we'll have to decide if we want to output a string with formatting applied or have it handled on the front-end.  im just surprised im having troubles finding a way to do it as a number

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting the value as raw data that can't be changed, try to change the formatting in your data layer.

`decimal value_formatted = Decimal.Parse(value.ToString("0.00"));`

which will give you a round-up to 2 decimal places in general.

`value.ToString("0.00")` is probably what you should do to ensure a presentation of 2 decimal places in term of string when the value has `.00`

Comment: i dont want to use a string, i would prefer to have it as a number in json